# Creating Filter Log for Logcat in Android Studip

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I have something like below logs coming in my android App

```
01-11 13:31:49.382 4060-4345/? D/VibratorService: Turning vibrator off - ImmVibe.
01-11 13:31:49.377 4060-4359/? I/InputDispatcher: Delivering touch to (12286): action: 0x0, toolType: 1
01-11 13:31:49.382 4060-4345/? V/VibratorService: vibrateMagnitude - package: com.example.moblecontrollerdemo, ms: 40, token: android.os.BinderProxy@26ff4724, magnitude: 4000
01-11 13:31:49.377 12286-12286/? D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
01-11 13:31:49.382 12286-12286/? V/Vibrator: Called vibrate(long) API!
01-11 13:31:49.382 12286-12286/? V/Vibrator: vibrate(long, AudioAttributes) API - PUID: 10477, PackageName: com.example.moblecontrollerdemo, ms: 40, AudioAttr: null
01-11 13:31:49.382 12286-12286/? V/Vibrator: Called vibrate(int, String, long, AudioAttributes) API - PUID: 10477, PackageName: com.example.moblecontrollerdemo
01-11 13:31:49.382 12286-12286/? V/Vibrator: vibrate - PUID: 10477, PackageName: com.example.moblecontrollerdemo, ms: 40, AudioAttr: null, mag: -1
```

How can I create filter of Logs having both D/ and V/ logs only.Also if possible to add D/abcTag and V/xyzTag as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and manage your filters from here:

[image: from here]

Answer (score 0):

@Raulp, Have you tried this..?

[image]